# Nativescript take screenshot of current screen programmatically

Tags: java, android, angular, typescript, nativescript

Is it any way after screenshot is created to nativescript app popup show and ask do you want to save this picture?

I tried with this plugin but it just copy element inside application:

```
nativescript-screenshot
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understood, you are asking what is the proper way to create a popup dialog to confirm or decline an action. If that's the issue then you could use `tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs`.

Example on how the confirm dialog is used to interact with the user can be found [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/29e915a5f6db530027760eead2eb70c8d5733538/app/pages/rovers/photo-detail.component.ts#L62-L77).

In [this documentation section](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/dialogs), you can find the dialog module description and example snippets

Comment: Hey Nick, I am not trying to do that. I am trying to capture screen of Android device place where are icons, clock and other things but not screen of application

Comment: apart from the user interaction (the button combination), I don't think there is a way to create "spy" screenshots of the user environment - nevertheless it is against the user privacy. Not sure if this is even possible in native Android